# Should we have a standard for editing questions like "Help me think of this game?"

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

Assuming that we allow [them](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/do-we-want-game-like-questions), should we come up with a standard way to edit question titles?

I just saw [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3509/what-is-the-name-of-this-game-where-you-have-to-construct-a-line-through-the-boar) and wanted to try and make it look a little better.  There's a big noise to signal ratio in the words chosen for the title.  The first significant word is "construct" which is the 12th word.

My thoughts would be standard questions titles like:

- Name this game: (edited text)
- Games similar to: (edited text)

They wouldn't even need to be enforced.  A few edits here and there would give the community enough example that I think people might start using them on their own and perhaps adopt new or better ones.

Is this a good idea?  If this is a bad idea, why would it be bad?  I can see perhaps the "[metatag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)" argument being used, but it is more about shrinking the insignificant question text down while keeping question readable.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're completely right and have edited it as such -- don't hesitate to click that edit link and submit edits like this in the future!

(also note that we do automatically insert the most significant tag into the HTML title of the page, so it gets coverage.)

Comment: As soon as I hit 200 rep I will!  (And don't forget to vote for questions, they need votes too ;) )

Comment: @mcl you can suggest edits anywhere even with 0 rep: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: I must be thinking of some other privilege then.  I need a privilege roadmap for dummy's picture.

Comment: @mcl there is always http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/privileges

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is you should always edit if you feel it will improve the question.

Edits can be rolled back anytime if someone disagrees.  We have yet to have an edit war here, but myself and the other mods will step in if necessary.